# Symfony2 : Set routing type in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I been searching for a solution to set the type of a routing in php.
In yml it can be done by:

```
_sonata_admin:
 resource: .
 type: sonata_admin
 prefix: /admin
```

In PHP I am importing it like so:

```
$routingImport = $loader->import(".");
$routingImport->addPrefix('/admin');
$collection->addCollection($routingImport );
```

It there a way to add a type parameter to this import like the one in yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the `Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader::$import` method is:

```php
public function import($resource, $type = null, $ignoreErrors = false, $sourceResource = null)
```

You can see that you can pass a type in the second argument:

```php
$routingImport = $loader->import('.', 'sonata_admin');
```